# Views and Workflow module

Tags: views, workflows

I am attempting to create a view that displays Content by it's current Workflow state.

I cannot see how this is possible using the Views module combined with the Workflow module.

Can you advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you enabled the "Workflow Views" module (in the workflow 'module')?
With it you get a example "workflow summary" view with a list of all content with its current state, title and type of the content.
In views you get access to a few new fields like "current state", "previous state", ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have also enabled the node access module, make sure that in the author settings per content type administration page you set the node author to be able to *view* and *edit*

Other wise it will not show in the workflow view.